# Can you use Imapsync to sync shared mailboxes from office 365

Tags: email, mail, office365

I use Imapsync for some time now to sync mail accounts from one to the other server. Now I have several shared mailboxes in office 365 that I have to transfer. Can this also be done via imapsync and how? :)